# Inherit properties from parent class without calling the parent method again in PHP

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

```
class A
{
    public $variable

    public function someFunction()
    {
        $this->variable = 'I am a variable';
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public function anotherFunction()
    {
        parent::someFunction();

        $stmt = $this->dbc->prepare('INSERT INTO table(row) VALUES(:variable)');
        $stmt->bindParam(':variable', $this->variable);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt = null;
        $dbc = null;
    }
}
```

How can I inherit `$variable` from 'class A' without calling again `someFunction()`.

The problem I have is that my 'class A' adds products to the basket and 'class B' inserts them into the database. When I call `someFunction()` in 'class B' to get all the product's details stored in properties in 'class A', it adds products to the basket again because the method is called twice, once in 'class A' and then again in 'class B'.

I could just keep all code in one class but that would break the SRP principle, wouldn't it?

**EDIT**: The code above is just to depict my problem, it's not an exact representation of my real script, hence there's nothing in it related with adding products to a basket. I'm just trying to keep things simple.

Comment: I removed `parent::someFunction();` and it works, which now seems logical as precisely that piece of code calls the function again. I though it was necessary to access properties stored in that method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `class A` and `class B` are two completely different instances. If you have an instance of `class A`, nothing you do in that will be reflected in your `class B` instance.

When extending, see it as `class B` is a different class that only uses `class A` as a base template.

Instead of extending it, you can pass your `class A` instance into `class B` instance so `class B` can get it's data directly from the `class A`-instance.

Example:

```
class A
{
    public $var;

    public function doStuff()
    {
        $this->var = 'Foobar';
    }
}

class B
{
    public function doOtherStuff(A $classA)
    {
        // Now you can get the data from class a
        $var = $classA->var;

        // Do you db stuff
    }
}

$classA = new A();
$classA->doStuff();

$classB = new B();
$classB->doOtherStuff($classA);
```

Comment: Many thanks for that! Both ways work but I'm just a noob and was wandering if there is any benefit of using one way or another.

Comment: @yendrrek - Your current setup requires you to keep two objects in sync. If you do anything in class A that class B needs (like adding values), you need to manually do it in class B as well. So it might seem to work in some situations, but it doesn't work in the way you think (based on your question).

Comment: Should be `$var = $classA->var;` (minor typo, I'm sure OP got the idea).

Comment: @Jeto - Darn. Thanks! Updated.

Comment: Actually what worked for me was the following: `$this->var = $classA->var;`  Many thanks for your help, guys. From what I have gathered so far, the way Magnus has shown here is called 'Composition' and it may be better than 'Inheritance' as it prevents coupling of classes. An article I've found: https://www.amitmerchant.com/reasons-use-composition-over-inheritance-php/

Comment: @yendrrek If you're going to set it to a class property, you should consider using *constructor injection* (as in dependency injection done via the class constructor) instead. See [here](https://designpatternsphp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Structural/DependencyInjection/README.html) for a basic example.